# How can I automatically add a new Row 2 every time I type data into row 2?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

... so that I can create an ever-expanding list and always enter the new data in row #2. (Row 1 is the header).

Currently, I have to go down to the bottom of the list to add new data or manually hit ADD NEW ROW each time.

Right now I have 6 columns per row. Though I'd like to create a new row if I put any data into any of the cells in Row 2.

Lastly, I would like preserve the formatting for the newly created row 2 that I currently have. (For example, I have all data automatically wrap. Some columns have drop down options to choose from, etc.).

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot imagine `Currently, I have to go down to the bottom of the list to add new data or manually hit ADD NEW ROW each time.`. And, about `Right now I have 6 columns per row. Though I'd like to create a new row if I put any data into any of the cells in Row 2.`, in this case, when a value is put to a cell, even when all 6 columns are not embedded, you want to move row 2. Is my understanding correct? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Think it has more to do with me not phrasing it correctly, then your poor english. ;)   In this example below, I'd like it so that if I type data into cell a2, the whole row will be shifted to row 3 (not just if I fill out data in A2:6).    The other part of the question is that in Row 2 I currently have drop-downs in cells c2 and d2 and all data is wrapped in the cells for Row 2.   When I enter a new row, can I preserve the drop-downs and formatting from the old Row 2 (which is now Row 3).     Thx!   https://i.stack.imgur.com/wg5bT.gif

Comment: Can you please provide a sample sheet with your input and desired output as well as the code/script you have worked on so that we can replicate your concern.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your expected situation. And, in your provided image is my image? From this image, I cannot understand your expected situation. I deeply apologize for this. As I have already mentioned in my 1st comment, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? I apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY:**

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getRow() === 2 ) {
      var ss = e.source; 
      var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
      var range = sheet.getRange("A2:F2").insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS); //Change the range as needed 
  }
}
```

In the code above,
The row *(in this case, I have set it from `A2` to `F2` which can be changed as needed)* will shift down, if you enter any data in any cell in `row 2` though while still preserving the formatting you've set.

**RESULT:**

[image]